# Web API with private video C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, video-streaming

I'm making a small web application which receives requests come from clients and respond a video stream back to them.

I have an api such as :

**[GET]api/video?id={videoId}**

which clients will pass their **Authorization token** in the header to receive video stream come from service (I don't want people who don't have permission to access the protected video on service - just like private video in Youtube).

I've read and implemented this tutorial : http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/

But, I'm wondering whether my implementation is the best approach or not ? Because my system is now small, but in future, I can become bigger to serve more and more clients.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I have the same issue and looking for the solution.

Comment: @JeyhunRahimov Did you find any solution for this problem?. I am also looking same solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to provide a "private" video, I believe that you can break the architecture into 2 base types:

- **Real protected access to the files** - there is NO real http physical access to the file (video), it is stored on the DB, or somewhere where only the IIS application pool user has access (disc/internal network/etc..)
- **FAKE protected access to the files** - where there is a real http path that will allow the access to the file, BUT the path is so "strange" and random... that the probability to find it is so low, that the user would simply not to spend time on trying to seek for "other things".... but of course, that with brute force or other things... after X time, probably something would "Pop-up".

You also pointed the fact of "starting" small, and grow bigger.... this is basically a high scalability design problem.... it all depends in so many things.... (starting with vertical or horizontal scaling).... caching, CDNs, replications, etc.....

Other factor: available resources (developers), money, "machines"(computers/servers), bandwith/speed, etc... number of current user and forecast of the future use..... etc.... with this I just want to say that sometimes the PRESENT solution is not the FUTURE solution, but it is the one that allows you to start and to make money.... and with "time" you can make it better with different "resources" available to you at that time.

With this being said: the article `Asynchronously streaming video with ASP.NET Web API` you pointed is a good startig point and it will work, but if you just want to make a FAST IMPLEMENTATION, just go first with the "FAKE PRIVATE" logic..... there you really do not need to worry about the "Asynchronous streaming" code, since the browser player will do this for you.